# Let $A$ be a square matrix, prove that $ker(A)$ is an subset of $ker(A^2)$ and $ker (A^2)$ is an subset of $ker(A^3)$

Tags: linear-algebra

I know that the the kernel of a vector L : V → W between two vector spaces V and W, is the set of all elements v of V for which L(v) = 0. From here on I have no  idea what to do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The statement

> $\ker(A)$ is a subset of $\ker(A^2)$

means

> if $\def\v{{\bf v}}\v$ is in $\ker(A)$, then $\v$ is in $\ker(A^2)$,

that is,

> if $A\v={\bf0}$ then $A^2\v={\bf0}$.

Assuming $A\v={\bf0}$, can you explain why $A^2\v={\bf0}$?

Comment: so if Av = 0, then (Av)A = 0 too, right? then A(0) = 0, and so on... is that how you prove it?

Comment: Almost, but $(A\v)A$ does not make sense, it has to be $A(A\v)$.

Answer (score 2):

Here's a hint: If $v\in\ker A$, then that means $Av = 0$ as you note. You want to show that if $v\in\ker A$, i.e. $Av = 0$, then $A^2 v = 0$ or equivalently $A(Av) = 0$. Do you see how to proceed?

By the way, you mean to say "is a subset of", not "is an element of" in your title.

Answer (score 2):

If $A$ is the matrix of the linear transformation $L$ then 
$A^2$ is the matrix of the linear transformation $L\circ L$.

Then $L(L(v))=L^(v)$

So $L^(v)=L(0)=0$

Similarly proceed with $A^3$

Answer (score 1):

More generally, just show that $\ker(B)\subseteq \ker(AB)$. This follows almost directly from the definition of $\ker$.