# Prove that if $\ker(A) = \ker(A^2 )$, then $ \ker(A^k ) = \ker(A^{k+1})$ for all $k ≥ 1$.

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $b$ be a vector such that $Ab =0$, and $b$ is that kernel. Let's call that kernel $A$. Then $b$ is also the same as $\ker(A^2)$.

Any hints would be appreciated on how to proceed further... Did I even do this right?

Comment: I think you might mean $ker(A^k) = ker (A^{k + 1})$, am I right?

Comment: haha yes you are... :o

Comment: Try $\LaTeX$ing $A^{k + 1}$ like this: A^{k + 1} . . .

Comment: @RobertLewis: Missing my Med Quesadillas...

Comment: @copper.hat:  yeah, you better get down here!  Cheers!

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1135890/let-a-be-a-square-matrix-prove-that-kera-is-an-subset-of-kera2-and

Answer (score 5):

It is clear that $\operatorname{ker}(A^k)\subseteq \operatorname{ker}(A^{k+1})$ unconditionally, since if $x\in\operatorname{ker}(A^k)$, then $A^kx=0$, so $A^{k+1}x=A(A^{k}x)=A0=0$. That is, $x\in\operatorname{ker}(A^{k+1})$.

Now suppose that $\operatorname{ker}(A)=\operatorname{ker}(A^2)$. The goal is to show that $\operatorname{ker}(A^{k+1})\subseteq \operatorname{ker}(A^{k})$. If $x\in\operatorname{ker}(A^{k+1})$, then $A^{k+1}x=A^2(A^{k-1}x)=0$. Hence, $A^{k-1}x\in\operatorname{ker}(A^2)=\operatorname{ker}(A)$, so that $A(A^{k-1} x)=0$. But this means that $A^k x=0$, so $x\in\operatorname{ker}(A^k)$. Consequently, $\operatorname{ker}(A^{k+1})\subseteq \operatorname{ker}(A^{k})$, as desired.

Answer (score 2):

$\ker A = \ker A^2$ is equivalent to $Ax = 0$ **iff** $A^2 x = 0$.

Replacing $x$ by $A^{k-1} x$ we get
$AA^{k-1}x = 0$ **iff** $A^2A^{k-1} x = 0$ which is equivalent to
$\ker A^k = \ker A^{k+1}$.